# Список методов определённых для структуры. golang

Tags: golang

Подскажите, есть ли возможность увидеть все методы определённые для структуры?
Поскольку на golang в определении структуры прописывать методы не требуется, и они идут сплошным кодом далее, то возникает вопрос как их посмотреть все одним списком...
Использую Visual Studio Code
Речь идёт о своём коде.
Сейчас я делаю комбинацию Ctrl+K+Ctrl+0 она схлопывает выделенный код оставляя  только определения функций. Почти, то что нужно. 
Но может есть ещё подход...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из терминала вы можете использовать `go doc`:

```
$ go doc json.Encoder
package json // import "encoding/json"

type Encoder struct {
    // Has unexported fields.
}
    An Encoder writes JSON values to an output stream.


func NewEncoder(w io.Writer) *Encoder
func (enc *Encoder) Encode(v interface{}) error
func (enc *Encoder) SetEscapeHTML(on bool)
func (enc *Encoder) SetIndent(prefix, indent string)
```

---

Чтобы показать документацию к пакету `main`, надо использовать флаг `-cmd`. Пример:

```
$ go doc -cmd golang.org/x/lint/golint
package main // import "golang.org/x/lint/golint"

golint lints the Go source files named on its command line.
```

Comment: в строке:  `$go doc json.Encoder`<br/>
json это название документируемого package, а Encoder - класс который мы документируем?<br/>
Проблема... на попытку сделать так <br/>
`go doc main.Las` где Las это мой класс выдаёт:<br/>
`doc: symbol main is not a type in package installed in "."`

Comment: Вам нужно использовать полное имя пакета. Так что если ваш пакет находится в `github.com/foo/bar`, то использовать надо как `go doc github.com/foo/bar.Struct`.

Comment: у меня не пакет, есть желание документировать саму  программу <br/>

     как вам удаётся здесь переносить текст на новую строку... и два пробела ставлю и <br/> ничего не помогает.

Comment: См. правку про флаг `-cmd` с примером.

Comment: Спасибо. -cmd не потребовалось. Достаточно было выполнить `go doc Las` при этом для класса Las текущего проекта я получил все поля и методы. Не забываем про флаг -u для отображения не экспортируемых полей и методов.